# How to emit a signal in a qtextedit when a string matches something?

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qt4, syntax-highlighting

I am developing a simple editor and in my editor i am trying to implement sth. like this: For example user types "void" then I emit a signal and somewhere in the gui will catch it and it will change itself. I am using the [syntax highlighter](http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html) example in my code and I emitted a signal in highlightBlock function:

```
void Highlighter::highlightBlock(const QString &text)
 {
     foreach (const HighlightingRule &rule, highlightingRules) {
         QRegExp expression(rule.pattern);
         if (expression.exactMatch("void")==true) {
             emit voidPrinted(2);

         }
         int index = expression.indexIn(text);
         while (index >= 0) {
             int length = expression.matchedLength();
         ...
     }
```

But when i run program, the signal always emitted without typing void. Documentation says "The highlightBlock() function is called automatically whenever it is necessary by the rich text engine, i.e. when there are text blocks that have changed." and I think I only emit when expression is void but apparently, I am wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You're running your regular expression over the string literal "void", rather than over the text the user typed in. Replace `expression.exactMatch("void")` with `expression.exactMatch(text)`. If you haven't already, you'll also need to add your "void" string as a pattern for the highlightingRules.

Also consider that adding a special signal for the 'void rule' to this method causes it to do multiple things. The rules are defined as data with a matcher and a specified highlighting to apply upon match, but you're hard-coding a special, unrelated behaviour for one of the matches. That suggests to me that you're going about things wrong, though without further study of the code you're working with, I couldn't tell you how to do things better.